# Using SWT and canvas, Moving line drawn with button

Tags: java, button, swt

I come to you in time of need once again. hehehe Ive done a little SWT which makes lines, circles, squares and triangles. I do this by taking the start point and the end point to draw all of these figures. once drawn I want to move it in x and y axis. Ill put here the core of where im having trouble. Im maing the lines by having a mouse listener inside the canvas, and hearing when i clicks down and lets go the click.
//This is the listener

MasX.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener(){

```
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            SX += 1;
            EX += 1;
            canvas.redraw();
            //gc.drawLine(SX, SY, EX, EY);
            //crearLinea(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

        }

    });
```

//This is  the line drawing method

```
public void crearLinea(int SX, int SY, int EX, int EY, GC gc){

    int x1 = SX;
    int x2 = EX;
    int y1 = SY;
    int y2 = EY;
    System.out.println(SX+" "+SY+" "+EX+" "+EY);
    int cont = 0;
    float dx, dy, m, y, x;
    if (x1>x2){
        int ax = x2;
        int ay = y2;
        x2 = x1;
        x1 = ax;
        y2 = y1;
        y1 = ay;
    }
    dx = x2 - x1;
    dy = y2 - y1;
    m = dy/dx;
    if (m>=-1&&m<=1){
        y = y1;
        //System.out.println(m+" "+x1+" "+y1+"....."+x2+" "+y2);
        for (x = x1 ; x <= x2;x=x+5){
            //if (x>=dot&&x<=dot+10||x>=dot*2&&x<=dot*2+10||x>=dot*3&&x<=dot*3+10){
                gc.drawLine((int)x, (int)Math.round(y), (int)x, (int)Math.round(y));
                y+=m*5;
            //}
        }   
    }
    if(m>1){
        x = x1;
        //System.out.println(m+" "+x1+" "+y1+"....."+x2+" "+y2);
        for (y = y1 ; y <= y2;y=y+3){
            if (cont<=5){
            //System.out.println(cont);
            gc.drawLine((int)Math.round(x), (int)y, (int)Math.round(x), (int)y);
            cont++;
            }
            if(cont>=10){
            //System.out.println(cont);
            cont=0;
            }
            if(cont>5){
            //System.out.println(cont);
            cont++;
            }
            x+=(1/m)*3; 
        }
    }
    if(m<-1){
        x = x1;
        //System.out.println(m+" "+x1+" "+y1+"....."+x2+" "+y2);
        for (y = y1 ; y >= y2;y--){
            if(y%10==0||y%8==0||y%12==0){
            gc.drawLine((int)Math.round(x), (int)y, (int)Math.round(x), (int)y);
            }
            x-=(1/m);   
        }
    }

}
```

The error it gives me is Null pointer exception and points to the gc.drawline()

Hope someone can help me :D

Answer (score 1):

The `Event.gc` is only set for `SWT.Paint` events, for the `SWT.Selection` listener you are using it will be `null`.

You can call one of the `Control.redraw` methods in the selection listener to request that part or all of the control be redrawn, this will generate a paint event.

Comment: I did this but all it does is put the canvas in white. Really good answer thought. I still dont know how to use the redraw method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This post helped me find the answer I was looking for. Ill post the answer in the next post.

Answer (score 0):

Like Greg told me to, I used the method canvas.redraw() which calles upon the canvas.addPaintListener(); method which then gives me the event im looking for to create the drawing I want. Here is the code to call it from the button:

```
MasX.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener(){

        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            SX += 10;
            EX += 10;
            System.out.println(SX+" "+SY+" "+EX+" "+EY);
            canvas.redraw();
            System.out.println("Aqui 2");
            //gc.drawLine(SX, SY, EX, EY);
            //crearLinea(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

        }

    });
```

And the core to call all the other methods which make the lines squares etc.

```
canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent event) {
            if(btnLinea.getSelection()){
                gc = event.gc;

                crearLinea(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

            }
            if(btnCirculo.getSelection()){
                gc = event.gc;

                crearCirculo(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

            }
            if(btnCuadrado.getSelection()){
                gc = event.gc;

                crearCuadro(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

            }
            if(btnTriangulo.getSelection()){
                gc = event.gc;

                crearTriangulo(SX,SY,EX,EY,gc);

            }
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps anyone :D